# how to show particular table head in jsp according request parameter from Servlet?

Tags: jsp, if-statement

Atttach tag to servlets attribute:

```
req.setAttribute("show", "itemList");
```

How to show table head according to attribute from servlets

```
 <table>
        <c:if test="${show="itemList"}">
                    <thead>
                        show info1
                    </thead>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${show="historyItemList"}">
                     <thead>
                        show info2
                     </thead>
         </c:if>

                    <tbody>
         <c:forEach items="${userItemsList}" var="item">
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${item.id}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${item.title}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${item.link}" /></td>
                    </tr>
         </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /userItems.jsp (line: 51, column: 36) equal symbol expected
>   What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the correct operator, and use single quotes:

```
<c:if test="${show == 'itemList'}">
```

or

```
<c:if test="${show eq 'itemList'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
<c:if test="${requestScope.show==\"itemList\"}">
```

and

```
<c:if test="${requestScope.show==\"historyItemList\"}">
```